# How can I access a child element of this JSON file with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Here's a Plunkr showing a basic ng-repeat rendering of a JSON file:

### [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/V1ct7J5OiSzuL3zJUGZq?p=preview)

I'm rendering elements from $scope.foodlist, like so:

```
        <li ng-repeat="food in foodlist">
            <p>Title: {{ food.title }}</p>
            <p>Code: {{ food.code }}</p>
            <p>Unit {{ food.unit }}</p>
        </li>
```

Because "unit" has a child element called "title", the above renders like so:

```
 Title: Walnußbrot
 Code: X 39 2000002
 Unit [{"title":"Scheiben"}]
```

Trying to target the title of the unit like this does not work:

```
 <p>Unit {{ food.unit.title }}</p>
```

How can I get the element "title" inside of "unit" to print? Do I need to add something extra to the Angular controller to target this child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unit` inside your json is a list.

So you need to do access the items either using indices or using `ng-repeat`:

```
<p>Unit {{ food.unit[0].title }}</p>
```

Or

```
<p ng-repeat="title in food.unit">Unit {{ title.title }}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me, what is it in the JSON that defines unit as a list?

Comment: The contents of `unit` are wrapped within `[` and `]` and that makes it a list.